# Laravel - How to add project from zip to vendor and use it?

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I try to add [php-webdriver](https://github.com/Element-34/php-webdriver) to my project via zip. I downloaded the zip and put it in my vendor folder. Unfortunately there is no install instruction for this case.

[image]

Next I created an autolader entry in **vendor\composer\autoload_psr4.php**:

```
...

'Facebook\\WebDriver\\' => array($vendorDir . '/facebook/webdriver/lib'),
'PHPWebDriver\\' => array($vendorDir . '/PHPWebDriver'),
'Dotenv\\' => array($vendorDir . '/vlucas/phpdotenv/src'),

...
```

Now in **app\Models\Selenium.php** I added this to the top:

```
namespace App\Models;

...

use PHPWebDriver;
use PHPWebDriver\WebDriverBase;
use PHPWebDriver\WebDriver;
```

and then use it in the same file:

```
$web_driver = new PHPWebDriver_WebDriver($Settings->SELENIUM_SERVER_ADDRESS);
$this->driver = $web_driver->session($Settings->TEST_BROWSER, $desiredCapabilities);
```

But I get

> FatalThrowableError in Selenium.php line 90: Class
>   'App\Models\PHPWebDriver_WebDriver' not found

which is at this line:

```
$web_driver = new PHPWebDriver_WebDriver($Settings->SELENIUM_SERVER_ADDRESS);
```

I don't know how to fix this, hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: Just run `composer require element-34/php-webdriver`, why are you trying to do it manually?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, because I try to solve this without composer or similar, and second I did not found `composer require element-34/php-webdriver` anywhere in the documentation. I did not knew that I could use it like this.

Comment: If any project you see has a composer.json https://github.com/Element-34/php-webdriver/blob/master/composer.json#L2, have a look at it, grab the name look it up on packagist https://packagist.org/packages/element-34/php-webdriver. You need to use composer, because fiddling with the vendor/composer/* will just be overwritten when you next run composer update.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, ahh thanks! Now I see! :)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, Ah wait. I tried it, but I still get `FatalThrowableError in Selenium.php line 90: Class 'App\Models\PHPWebDriver_WebDriver' not found`

Comment: Use: `$web_driver = new WebDriver($Settings->SELENIUM_SERVER_ADDRESS);`

Comment: Now I get `Class 'PHPWebDriver\WebDriver' not found` I think I should open another question for this...

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `use PHPWebDriver_WebDriver;` instead of:

```
use PHPWebDriver;
use PHPWebDriver\WebDriverBase;
use PHPWebDriver\WebDriver;
```